# Can't get jssor jQuery slider to fade with large images on fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I've tried everything and can not make it work. 
I'm trying to display images in full screen. 
The images are replaced but without the fade effect .

The pictures are large (500kb). Any suggestion?

```
var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            { 
            $Duration: 1000, 
            //$Delay: 300, 
            // $Cols: 8, 
            // $Rows: 4, 
            // $Top: true, 
            // $Right: true, 
            // $Bottom: true, 
            // $Left: true, 
             $Fade: true,
            //$SlideOut: true, 
            // $Assembly: 2049, 
            // $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, 
            // $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs 
            // $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs 
            }
];

var _options = {
                $PauseOnHover: 0,
                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                }
};


jssor_slider = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", _options);
```

Comment: Edit your question and add relevant HTML and css code that you used as well. Also provide us a playground such as http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following transition code,

```
{
    $Duration: 1000,
    //$Delay: 300, 
    // $Cols: 8, 
    // $Rows: 4, 
    // $Top: true, 
    // $Right: true, 
    // $Bottom: true, 
    // $Left: true, 
    $Opacity: 2
    //$SlideOut: true, 
    // $Assembly: 2049, 
    // $Easing: $Jease$.$OutQuad, 
    // $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs 
    // $Formation: $JssorSlideshowFormations$.$FormationStraightStairs 
}
```

Btw, you can copy slideshow code later here http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html